# Automatic update - malware?

Tags: windows-10, malware

I get this "automatic update" box appear on my windows 10 box every few days. It doesn't look genuine to me, it looks like the sort of thing that's installed by malware.

[image: Automatic Update]

Everything in my startup box on task manager is set to disabled. I can't see the icon for this program in Task Manager -> Processes. I've not been able to identify it using Google.

Have you seen anything like this before and can identify it? Can you tell me how to remove it?

Comment: It appears to be malware. Bing Terms of Service and Chromium is what flags it has not being legitimate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks sketchy to me. Malwarebytes might help hunt it down.

To nail down the exact process, download  [process explorer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer). It has a little tool that looks like crosshairs, drag the cross hairs over the Window and it will select the process.

Deleting it might be as simple as deleting the related process, but it might be a bit deeper embedded, that is why I suggested Malwarebytes, but you could also google the process name and look around. If you get to a website that describes it, and then tells you to download a tool from the website, don't unless it is a reputable anti-virus company.

Comment: Malware bytes picked up a few unwanted applications with "Bing" in the title. I've removed them all and not seen it since. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

> Have you seen anything like this before and can identify it?

Not that exact image, but I've seen "offers" for downloading browsers from unexpected sources.

This is unquestionably not desired.  It offers Chromium, which is a legitimate product by Google, and Bing, which is a search engine offered by Microsoft.  If this was really Microsoft-endorsed, it wouldn't be pushing Chromium, and if Google was behind this then it wouldn't be using Bing.

> Can you tell me how to remove it?

Use the open source [Process Hacker](http://processhacker.sf.net/downloads.php) (or Process Explorer, as mentioned by user173724's answer) to find out what executable this is.

As for how to remove the program, consider using [Autorunsc](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns) to help with that.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Chrome? I got this pop-up today and since then when I created a new tab in Chrome, the home page was a fake Bing. Turns out it's caused by a Chrome extension called utab Deleted it and the new tab page was immediately back to normal and I didn't get the update pop-up since.